# Is it possible to store stablecoins on blockchain and transfer them?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

imagine an app where we can create events with prizes on the blockchain. At the beginning of the event the creator puts a certain amount of dollars into the prize pool. A few days later the event is done and the money is transferred to winner blockchain addresses.

Is there any block chain or solution that would allow me to implement this system with stablecoin prize pools and not rely on something like BNB/ETH/SOL which is volatile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the solution using ERC-20 stablecoins as well.

The user needs to invoke `approve()` function on the token address, passing it your contract address as a parameter, specifying that they are approving you to manipulate the predefined amount of their tokens. This step is required because of how the ERC-20 tokens are designed, and is implemented all applications that are spending your ERC-20 tokens. For example if you want to buy token XYZ for USDT on Uniswap, their frontend app asks you to approve them your USDT first.

Then you can invoke the `transferFrom()` function of the token from your contract, passing it the sender (the user), receiver (your contract), and the amount as params.

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract MyContract {
    // mainnet Ethereum address of the USDT contract
    // because of the hardcoded address, this snippet works only on the mainnet and its forks
    IERC20 usdt = IERC20(address(0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7));

    function depositUSDT(uint256 amount) public {
        // reverts if the user has not approved `MyContract` address to manipulate their tokens
        usdt.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had no idea where to start looking into this. Does a similar approach work with BUSD or USDC too?

Comment: @vladCovaliov Yes, as long as they follow the ERC20 standard. (Which these specific tokens do.)